# Jmeter. Как значения полей из БД использовать в http запросах?

Tags: jdbc, jmeter

Кто знает как в Jmeter данные из  БД использовать в запросах? Например есть шаг - предусловие выборка из БД по JDBC, затем есть http запрос,- в который я хочу подставлять эти значения. Причем если будет несколько потоков то нужно чтобы значения из базы не повторялись (по аналогии чтения из csv).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант 1:

- [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)

  - [JDBC PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_PreProcessor) чтобы вытащить значение для **текущего** запроса на уровне SQL

Вариант 2:

- [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) с условием `${__threadNum} == 1 && ${__groovy(vars.getIteration() == 1,)}` (чтобы запрос выполнился только 1 раз)

  - [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action)

    - JDBC PreProcessor чтобы вытащить **все** значения из БД
- HTTP Request с использованием той же функции [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) или [__counter()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) чтобы каждый поток использовал свое значение.

Вариант 3: тоже самое что и Вариант 2, только с использованием [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) для итерации по результатам запроса

Вариант 4: записать результат запроса в CSV файл с помощью [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) и использовать обычный CSV Data Set Config